# Need to find which is foreign key in sqlite3 table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a two tables that are linked and am using ruby on rails.  I need to find out what the foreign key is from the command prompt.  How can I find the foreign key from the sqlite3 console?

Answer (score 1):

The association is defined within Rails, not within sqlite3.

Check your models in app/models in your Rails project.

You should see some sort of relation defined... `belongs_to` or `has_many` or `has_one` ... there are other possibilities but if you only have the two tables then they don't apply.

If the definition doesn't specifically mention a foreign_key then you can interpret the foreign key from the models' names...

for example

```
class Teacher
has_many students
```

that tells you that there's a foreign key on the students table called "teacher_id"

```
class Student
belongs_to teacher
```

that tells you that there's a foreign key on the students table called "teacher_id" (the same foreign key as above).

This should give you some familiarity with how associations work in Rails...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: While the association may be defined by Rails, who's to say a foreign key column (`teacher_id`) in the students table was actually created?

Comment: Well, the OP said the tables are linked, so I presumed (possibly wrongly) there's a working association. OP didn't ask what the fk should be, he asked how he can retrieve it.

Comment: I need to find out what is it already because there are two values of in the table that have very similar names. A table called Rooms and a table called People.  I need to find out the foreign key from the People table and the columns are named "id","name", and "room_id".  I am not sure which the foreign key is set to already.

Comment: It's a pretty safe guess that "room_id" is the foreign key in people that points to rooms  In the "Person" model (app/models/person.id) it likely says `belongs_to :room`

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key is usually always within the model its connected to.

So suppose I have a user object that has an account object. The account object's foreign id would be `user_id`, or vice versa, `account_id` in the User table.

But if you need to explore more, you can open your schema.rb to find out exactly what that's called.

Within the console you can also do :

```
Model.column_names
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sqlite3 utility with your sqlite3 file (eg. sqlite3 database.db), and try command:

```
.schema ?TABLE?        Show the CREATE statements
                         If TABLE specified, only show tables matching
                         LIKE pattern TABLE.
```

To list tables:

```
.tables ?TABLE?        List names of tables
                         If TABLE specified, only list tables matching
                         LIKE pattern TABLE.
```